# Quarkus Kafka - Batch/Bulk message consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I want to batch process. In my use case send kafka producer messages are sent one by one. I want to read them as a list in the consumer application. I can do that at the Spring Kafka library. [Spring Kafka batch listener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#batch-listeners)

Is there any way to do this with the **quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka** library?

I tried the example below but got an error.

```java
ERROR [io.sma.rea.mes.provider] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) SRMSG00200: The method org.MyConsumer#aggregate has thrown an exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.TestConsumer cannot be cast to class io.smallrye.mutiny.Multi (org.TestConsumer is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @6f2c0754; io.smallrye.mutiny.Multi is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @4c1638b)
```

application.properties:

```java
kafka.bootstrap.servers=hosts
mp.messaging.connector.smallrye-kafka.group.id=KafkaQuick
mp.messaging.connector.smallrye-kafka.auto.offset.reset=earliest
mp.messaging.incoming.test-consumer.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.test-consumer.value.deserializer=org.TestConsumerDeserializer
```

TestConsumerDeserializer:

```java
public class TestConsumerDeserializer extends JsonbDeserializer<TestConsumer>{
    public TestConsumerDeserializer(){
         // pass the class to the parent.
         super(TestConsumer.class);
    }
}
```

MyConsumer:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyConsumer {
    
    @Incoming("test-consumer")
    //@Outgoing("aggregated-channel")
    public void aggregate(Multi<Message<TestConsumer>> in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could collect the data yourself to a Queue, then process/empty it when it reaches a set size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch support has been added to the Quarkus Kafka connector.
See https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#receiving-kafka-records-in-batches.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the reason why the ClassNotFoundException in the question.
But I found solutions for reading bulk/bach messages using `quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka`.

Solution 1:

```java
@Incoming("test-consumer-topic")
@Outgoing("aggregated-channel")
public Multi<List<TestConsumer>> aggregate(Multi<TestConsumer> in) {
     return in.groupItems().intoLists().every(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
}

@Incoming("aggregated-channel")
public void test(List<TestConsumer> test) {
   System.out.println("size: "+ test.size());
}
```

Solution 2:

```java
@Incoming("test-consumer-topic")
@Outgoing("events-persisted")
public Multi<Message<TestConsumer>> processPayloadStream(Multi<Message<TestConsumer>> messages) {
    return messages
                    .groupItems().intoLists().of(4)
                    .emitOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())
                    .flatMap(messages1 -> {
                        persist(messages1);
                        return Multi.createFrom().items(messages1.stream());
                    }).emitOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultExecutor());
}

public void persist(List<Message<TestConsumer>> messages){
    System.out.println("messages size:"+ messages.size());
}

@Incoming("events-persisted")
public CompletionStage<Void> messageAcknowledging(Message<TestConsumer> message){
    return message.ack();
}
```

note: Using the application.properties config in the question.

references:

[Support subscribing with Multi<Message<>>...](https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-reactive-messaging/issues/804)

[Get Bulk polled message from kafka](https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-reactive-messaging/issues/925)